# Binary operation to get / set property

Tags: php, binary-operators

I would like to store user rights as integer in database, but not sure how... How does it work on PHP with for example [error_reporting()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) ?

You got different constants, like... `E_ERROR` = 1, `E_WARNING` = 2, `E_PARSE` = 4, `E_NOTICE` = 8 etc... and you can set it like `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_NOTICE)` ...

In this case `E_WARNING | E_NOTICE` == 10.

Ok, so I do understand that this is binary operation "OR" and as far as consecutive constants are multiplied by 2, everything should be reversable... but how?

So I got this (int)10. And how do I check that it is `E_WARNING` and `E_NOTICE`?

PS. I do understand that it is `1010` on binary notation.

Comment: Doesn't your DBMS support the `SET` datatype?

Comment: @Barmar not sure what do you mean.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Comment: @Barmar this is cool, didn't hear about it before... still doesn't apply for user right, as I cannot query database everytime i need to determinate if user has that right or not...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if values are *set*, you can use the bitwise AND `&` operator.

```
$warningEnabled = $val & E_WARNING;
```

This works because (assume `$val` is `128`)...

```
1000 0000 & # $value
0000 0010   # E_WARNING
```

Since the same bit isn't set in both, you can tell that `$val` doesn't have warnings set.

You can execute this in PHP if you like with [`bindec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) function (wrap the above values as strings), it may help you understand better.

Comment: Yes I do understand that... had some other concept, but this should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the value contains `E_WARNING`, do:

```
if ($value & E_WARNING)
```